# Visual Studio Team Explorer + VS Online Sync error

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, team-explorer

I'm using VS Online + Git for Version Control, and everything worked fine for a long time until yesterday, when I reinstalled windows  and installed VS 2015. I've opened VS and chose option Open from source control and connected to my VS online account, but when I tried to clone project to my PC I got error:

```
Error encountered while fetching: Invalid redirect to a non-git endpoint
```

I've tried few things (mostly randomly because I could not find anything helpful about this err) and nothing helped.

Then I've opened Git bash and manually cloned project to my PC and that wen without any problems. After that I opened project in VS and did some changes, committed dose changes locally without any problems, but when I tried to Sync my project I got same error again. Again, pushing code to server from Git bash went without any problems.

Also I've tried to clone project from another VS online account trough VS + Team Explorer and that went fine.

Could you please help me ?

Comment: same here, i started experiencing this a few days ago, happened out of the blue and only on one of my laptop, i have two other machines signed into visual studio with the same microsoft account with no issue.  I even reset the laptop and reinstall vs2015 and to my surprise i still get the same error.

Comment: I tested this with another VSO account and it worked fine, so i'm guessing this issue is VSO account specific.  The only thing I can think of that happened around the same time I got the issue is the VSO account trial ended.  Wonder if that has anything to do with it.  @hyperN do you happen to have your VSO trial ended recently as well?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply, but that is not issue for me, I have full MSDN subscription

Comment: @Wil cannot comment, but has noted that you could try signing out of VS, as mentioned in [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48d38556-32cb-4214-a849-a51cc148ea23/cant-access-visual-studio-online-after-switching-from-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-to-visual?forum=TFService).

Comment: @Wil also asks, "when in Team Explorer, do other actions work like querying work items?"

Comment: If you have this issue then vote on Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1981348

Comment: @cgmb Other things work, I haven't had time lately to try thing you suggested, but because push / pull work trough git bash so this isn't major issue for me at the moment (I have much more pressing tasks)

Answer (score 3):

To resolved this I had to logout of Team Foundation Server. In VS 2015, in the Team tab, select "Disconnect from Team Foundation Server". You can close VS and restart it if you choose but I don't think that makes a difference. When VS is back up go to the Team tab once again and select "Manage Connections", then click on the "Manage Connections" link then follow the steps to login.

Comment: Hey, that didn't help :/

Comment: tried disconnecting VSO from Azure subscription and Azure AD and reconnect, still no luck, quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered same problem just now - after some google-fu nothing changed. But then tried following steps and it worked (push manually before doing it or safe your changes somewhere):

- close solution
- delete whole directory where your repo is located
- (in Team Explorer View) clicked on the repo name(that small down-arrow)
- there: projects > manage connections
- rightclick your repo and delete it (could be you have to change to another one, otherwise you cant delete it while you have loaded it)
- clone your repo back to where it was

after these steps i was able synch again

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I managed to resolved it by going to Team Explorer -> Manage Connections -> Connect To Team Project -> Servers and removing all my TFS servers. Also, I had to sign out with all my accounts from Visual Studio, restart VS and login again and connect to GIT.

At the end I added back my TFS servers.